# Create setter Expression<Action<object, object>> from Expression<Func<IMyclass, int>>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have an `Expression<Func<IMyclass, int>>` which I want to convert to a setter typed as `Expression<Action<object, object>>`. How can that be achieved?

The problem is the `object` parameter. With the correct type (`string`) this would be easy.

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
class Bar
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }    
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var expr = GetExpression(t => t.Bar.Baz);
    var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
    // This does not work...
    var assign = Expression.Assign(member, p);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(assign, p);

    object o = new Foo();
    object v = "test";
    lambda.Compile().Invoke(o, v);
}

private static Expression<Func<Foo, string>> GetExpression(Expression<Func<Foo, string>> expr)
{
    return expr;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible but not quite trivial. First you need to rewrite your original expresion. Now it has this form:

```
(Foo t) => t.Bar.Baz;
```

You need it to be like this:

```
(object t) => ((Foo)t).Bar.Baz;
```

So you need expression visitor:

```
private class ReplaceParameterExpressionVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly ParameterExpression _toReplace;
    private readonly ParameterExpression _replaceWith;
    public ReplaceParameterExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression toReplace, ParameterExpression replaceWith) {
        _toReplace = toReplace;
        _replaceWith = replaceWith;
    }            

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
        if (node == _toReplace)
            // replace with new parameter and convert to the old parameter type
            return Expression.Convert(_replaceWith, _toReplace.Type);
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var expr = GetExpression(t => t.Bar.Baz);
    var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;

    // define new parameter of type object
    var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "t");
    var value =  Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p");
    // replace old parameter of type Foo to new one
    member = (MemberExpression) new ReplaceParameterExpressionVisitor(expr.Parameters[0], target).Visit(member);
    // convert value to target type, because you cannot assign object to string
    var assign = Expression.Assign(member, Expression.Convert(value, member.Type));
    // now we have (target, value) => ((Foo)target).Bar.Baz = (string) value;
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(assign, target, value);

    var o = new Foo();
    // set bar or will throw null reference
    o.Bar = new Bar();
    object v = "test";
    lambda.Compile().Invoke(o, v);
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Can this be done without ExpressionVisitor? Or would that be more complicated?

Comment: Yes this will be much more complicated, because you will have to actually do the same visitor already doing for you, but yourself. Expression trees are immutable, so you cannot just modify some parts of it - you need to create new tree.

Comment: I think you should be able to simplify your visitor: change to `Expression.Convert` in `VisitParameter` and get rid of `VisitMember`.